# How to convert the value of a column to rows -dataframgroupby

Tags: python

I have a table of "Borrower Personal ID" and "Loan ID".

```
BwrPersonld LoanId
113225  16330
113225  27073
113225  68842
113253  16341
113269  16348
113285  16354
113289  26768
113297  16360
113299  16361
113319  16369
113418  16403
113418  26854
```

I'm trying to know which loans belong to the same borrower. So I "groupby" the "BwrPersonalId" and "LoanId" like below.

[image]

Now I'm expecting like this.

[image]

Here is my code, but it doesn't work.

```
grouped = pd.DataFrame()
unique = loan['BwrPersonId'].unique()
grouped['BwrPersonId'] = ''*len(loan['BwrPersonId'].unique())
grouped['Loan1'] = ''
grouped['Loan2'] = ''
grouped['Loan3'] = ''
grouped['Loan4'] = ''
grouped['Loan5'] = ''
grouped.iloc[:,0] = unique
for i in grouped.index:
    idloan = loan.loc[loan['BwrPersonId'] == unique[i], 'LoanId']
    grouped.iloc[i,1:len(idloan)+1] = idloan
    print(i)
```

How can I do it now? And is there any other way that can simplify the code? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Just so you know, the raw data you provided does not match the date you grouped by. I went ahead and created a raw data set based on your grouped data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you need to do is create a temp that will be utilizing the data that will be sorted, and the name that will be in charge of the Id to sort the Ids according to the loans.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count

dict = defaultdict(count)
id, name = pd.factorize([*zip(grouped.id, grouped.name)])
joined = np.array([next(dict[x]) for x in id])
lenOfr, Max = len(name), joined.max() + 1
temp = np.empty((lenOfr, Max), dtype=np.object)
temp[id, joined] = grouped.LoanId
df1 = pd.DataFrame(name.tolist(), columns=['BwrPersonId'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(temp, columns=['Loan1', 'Loan2', 'Loan3', 'Loan4', 'Loan5'])
final = df1.join(df2)
```